# Loop for iterating through two lists is not working

Tags: python, pandas, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to use a loop for iterating through two lists. Unfortunately, the second for loop does not work: it only checks the first item within the list, but not with rest.
Could you please tell me why?

Thanks

Lists:

```
low_cars_engines=['Audi', 'Bentley', 'Bugatti', 'Porsche', 'Skoda']
low_planes_engines=['Pratt & Whitney','Rolls-Royce','GE Aviation']
```

I would like to add two more columns (Cars and Planes) to my original dataset based on if statements:

- if an object from list 'Engine to check' is in the list low_cars_engines, then it is a car, otherwise, it is not;
- if an object from the list 'Engine to check' is in the list low_planes_engines, then it is a plane, otherwise, it isn't.

```
import re

df['Cars'] = pd.Series(index = df.index, dtype='object')
df['Planes'] = pd.Series(index = df.index, dtype='object')

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    value = row['Engine to check']
    for x in low_cars_engines:
        if x in value:
            print(x)
            df.at[index,'Cars'] = 'Yes' # need to keep df.at[index, '_']
            break
        else: 
            df.at[index,'Cars'] = 'No' # need to keep df.at[index, '_']
            break

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    value = row['Engine to check']
    for x in low_planes_engines:
        if x in value:
            df.at[index,'Planes'] = 'Yes'
            break
        else: 
            df[index,'Planes'] = 'No'
            break

print(df)
```

The first for loop works fine, but not the second: I am not able to assign a value to an item in the list 'Engine to check' even if it is within the list low_planes_engines (it gives me always No).

Could you please tell me what is wrong and if it would be possible to use only one for loop rather than two? I would prefer to keep the same structure, or keep `df.at[index,'_']`. Right now the second loop print/check only the first item of the list low_planes_engines (i.e. Pratt & Whitney) and does not go through the rest.

Since the dataset is similar to:

```
Audi
CFM International
Rolls-Royce
Bentley
Volkswagen
Toyota
Suzuki
Porsche
```

and it does not include that element, all the rows under `Planes` are set to `No`.

Comment: You have `break` in both `if` branches, so the loops never continue.

Comment: What is in the column 'Engine to check'? There is a space in the second occurrence that might be unintentional and preventing the second loop from working.

Comment: Yes, sorry, it was a typo. I fixed in the post. There was no space in the code. It was my fault when I copied it here

Comment: You can probably replace your loop with `df["Cars"] = df['Engine to check'].isin(low_cars_engines)`

Comment: I tried but it set all the values to True

Comment: How are web site names related to engine models? Which is your _real_ dataset and what do you _really_ try to solve?

Comment: The problem is not in the dataset that I am going to use but in the code that unfortunately  is not working for any dataset (engines, websites...), so I am trying to understand if the problem is in my notebook

Comment: Maybe there's something up with the way the values are stored - is it a column of string values? Or are there lists within each row?

Comment: values come from a csv file and they are column of string values. The problem in my code is that the first loop works fine, but the other one not. I have also tried with a different dataset, but probably I cannot apply what DYZ suggested as it is a subset that I should consider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use loops when you work with Pandas. DataFrames are not designed to be accessed sequentially. You need some NumPy, though:

```
import numpy as np
df['Cars']   = np.where(df['Engine to check'].isin(low_cars_engines), 'Yes', 'No') 
df['Planes'] = np.where(df['Engine to check'].isin(low_planes_engines), 'Yes', 'No')
```

Result:

```
#     Engine to check Cars Planes
# 0               Audi  Yes     No
# 1  CFM International   No     No
# 2        Rolls-Royce   No    Yes
# 3            Bentley  Yes     No
# 4         Volkswagen   No     No
# 5             Toyota   No     No
# 6             Suzuki   No     No
# 7            Porsche  Yes     No
```

You probably should not use "Yes" and "No," either. Use boolean values `True` and `False` instead, as they are easier to work with in the future:

```
df['Cars']   = df['Engine to check'].isin(low_cars_engines) 
df['Planes'] = df['Engine to check'].isin(low_planes_engines)
```

Finally, if everything in the DataFrame is strictly a car or a plane, only one column is required. The other will be the complement.

Comment: The problem is that sets all the values to True/false when this is not True

Comment: No, it does not. I included the results computed with your data.

Comment: I do not know what is happening in my code, but it does not work. Could you please also try with this list? (I am going to update the dataset in a few minutes). Thanks

Comment: I updated the code. could you please try with this new dataset? I think there is something that it is not working (maybe in the program, rather than in the code). It should do pretty the same. Thank you so much

Comment: Wait, you compare Web site addresses to engine names, and you expect them to match?

Comment: it is another dataset with another columns, but it uses the same structure of code that I shown on the top. It is just to test the code that you used as it is not working when I try it. So I am using a different dataset (you do not have to compare with engines. The whole dataset and code is in the edited part)

Comment: It does not use a _similar_ structure. In the new dataset, you look for subsets, not for exact matches. I suggest you delete this question and ask it again, correctly.

Comment: I cannot delete the question. I am sorry. I can create a new one with another dataset.

Answer (score 1):

You have an additional space here

```
row['Engine to check ']
```

Try changing it to

```
row['Engine to check']
```

Comment: it is not because of that. Sorry, that was a typo in copying the code here. How should I edit the break in the statements?

Comment: I would use a lambda expression and apply function it is easy to read and no loops involved, something like this `df['Cars'] =  df.apply(lambda x: 'Yes' if x['Engine to check'] in low_cars_engines else 'No', axis=1)` and `df['Planes'] =  df.apply(lambda x: 'Yes' if x['Engine to check'] in low_planes_engines else 'No', axis=1)`