# Loop for iterating through two lists

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to use a loop for iterating through two lists. This question is related to this, but with another dataset that I am testing for similar purpose: [Loop for iterating through two lists is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61070285/loop-for-iterating-through-two-lists-is-not-working?noredirect=1#comment108041917_61070285) .

I would like to add two more columns (`Test_1` and `Test_2`) to my original dataset based on if statements:

- if an object from list '`To_test`' is/contains a word in the list `low_test_1`, then it is `Yes`, otherwise it is `No`;
- if an object from list '`To_test`' is/contains a word in the list `low_test_2`, then it is `Yes`, otherwise it `No`.

Could you please how to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because values in test_1 are not exactly in the df['Test_1'].

For example, record with index 201257 has 'ansa.it' not 'ansa'.
Thus, for your purpose, try this code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np  

def part_is_in(x, values):
    output = 'No'
    for val in values:
        if val in x:
            return 'Yes'
            break                
    return output

df['Test_1'] = df['To_test'].apply(part_is_in, values = low_test_1)
df['Test_2'] = df['To_test'].apply(part_is_in, values = low_test_2)
```